# How to hide text in menu on hover and put image with underline instead?

Tags: html, css

I want to make menu on top, and on hover mouse to hide text and display icon. And to add underline under icon.In my code i successfully change text to image but how to add underline under image and make underline 3px wight and 60px length?
There is my code- HTML:

```
<div class="menu topMenu">
<ul class="topMenuOptions">
    <li><span>111</span></li>
    <li><span>222</span></li>
    <li><span>333</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.topMenu {
text-transform: uppercase;
background-image: url('images/1.png');
position: absolute;
height: 88px;
width: 400px;
background: lightcoral;
margin-left: 332px;
padding-top: 30px;
 }

.topMenuOptions {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
margin-left: 155px;
list-style-type: none;
}

.topMenuOptions li {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline;
}

    .topMenuOptions li:hover:nth-child(1) {
        background: url('images/2.png') center center no-repeat;
        background-position: 20px 0;
        background-size: contain;
        color:transparent;
    }

    .topMenuOptions li:hover:nth-child(2) {
        background: url('images/3.png') center center no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        background-position: 20px 0;
        color: transparent;
    }

      .topMenuOptions li:hover:nth-child(3) {
        background: url('images/4.png') center center no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        background-position: 20px 0;
        color: transparent;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `border-bottom: 3px solid white;`, for example:

```
.topMenuOptions li:hover:nth-child(1) {
    background: url('images/2.png') center center no-repeat;
    background-position: 20px 0;
    background-size: contain;
    color:transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, I made a fiddle which you can check.

for the underline, you can keep border-bottom of 3px with border-color initially as transparent. this transparent color is required by default to avoid the jerking of the text when a border is added on hover.

I have modified your code a bit just for your understanding.

```css
.topMenu {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-image: url('images/1.png');
    position: absolute;
    height: 88px;
    width: 400px;
    background: lightcoral;
   /*  margin-left: 332px; */
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.topMenuOptions {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 155px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.topMenuOptions li {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

.topMenuOptions li:hover:nth-child(1) {
    background: url('http://php.quicoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/css3.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0;
    background-size: contain;
    color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
}

.topMenuOptions li:hover:nth-child(2) {
    background: url('http://php.quicoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/css3.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: 0px 0;
    color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
}

.topMenuOptions li:hover:nth-child(3) {
    background: url('http://php.quicoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/css3.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: 0px 0;
    color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu topMenu">
<ul class="topMenuOptions">
    <li><span>111</span></li>
    <li><span>222</span></li>
    <li><span>333</span></li>
</ul>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/avijitkr/erzv4oms/)

Answer (score 0):

```
`<ul>
    <li class="option">
        <span id="text">111</span>
        <span id="image" class="hide">IMAGE</span>
    </li>
    <li class="option">
        <span id="text">222</span>
        <span id="image" class="hide">IMAGE</span>
    </li>
</ul>`


.option:hover .option > #image
{
display:block;
border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
.option:hover: .option > #text
{
display:none;
}
.hide
{
display:none;
}
```

you can do something like this, which is more efficient,
inside the image span you can add a image tag, which will also do the job.